# Speeding-up processing of pair-wise distance calculation in Python?

Tags: python, performance, proximity, code-review

I am trying to do a cluster analysis using DBSCAN for my time series NDVI image in Python. I am using distance time warping (DTW) to measure distances between my time series. With this, I am computing pairwise distances using DTW which will be eventually be an input to DBSCAN. My problem, pairwise calculation seems very slow. I browsed some techniques, such as multithreading, GPU programming, splitting data into blocks. I would like to ask, which could be the approach to speed-up my processing for calculating pairwise distances. An approach that I can simply implement on a 2-core x 8GBRAM x i7 processor laptop.

Some information:

The input numpy table (**mod_hypercube.npy**) is an output of image stacking which I did in my other script. It is an image stack stored as numpy table.

The DBSCAN parameters are still experimental, will explore different combinations when I have the pairwise metric.

The numpy table dimension is

```
In [4]: t.shape
Out[4]: (138L, 624L, 645L)
```

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math,gc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

def DTWDistance(s1, s2):
    DTW={}
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        DTW[(i, -1)] = float('inf')
    for i in range(len(s2)):
        DTW[(-1, i)] = float('inf')
    DTW[(-1, -1)] = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        for j in range(len(s2)):
            dist= (s1[i]-s2[j])**2
            DTW[(i, j)] = dist + min(DTW[(i-1, j)],DTW[(i, j-1)], DTW[(i-1, j-1)])
    return math.sqrt(DTW[len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1])

t = np.load("E:\\file\\path\\mod_hypercube.npy")

distMatrix = np.empty(shape=(t.shape[1] * t.shape[2],t.shape[1] * t.shape[2]))

# this is the dimension of the hypercube matrix
idx = 0
for r in range(0,t.shape[1]):
    for c in range(0,t.shape[2]):

        X = t[:,r,c] 
        idx_2 = 0
        distances = np.empty(shape=(t.shape[1] * t.shape[2]))
        for j in range(0,t.shape[1]):
            for k in range(0,t.shape[2]):
                y = t[:,j,k]
                distances[idx_2] = np.round(DTWDistance(X,y),2)
                idx_2 += 1

        distMatrix[idx] = distances
        print "this is idx1=%s" %idx
        idx += 1

np.savetxt("E:\\file\\path\\distMatrix.csv", distMatrix, delimiter=",")
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10,metric="precomputed").fit(distMatrix)
# parameters=‘auto’, ‘ball_tree’, ‘kd_tree’, ‘brute’
#(eps=0.5, min_samples=5, metric=’euclidean’, metric_params=None, algorithm=’auto’, leaf_size=30, p=None, n_jobs=1)
print db.labels_

plt.imshow(distMatrix)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your looping in python is going to be super slow.  Either [vectorise and remove the loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903795/737471), then try using `numexpr` on the vectorised expression (I got >100x speedup for pairwise differencing by doing this) or keep your explicit loops and use `numba` to just-in-time compile the loops to native code.

Comment: Luke, can you give some simple example codes that I can build on. for instance, if I have a simple 3D matrix? sample here (its just a snapshot): https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhnftno09szvype/sample.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Suggest you have a go and post where you get stuck.

Comment: @Luke does this mean I have to transpose my z dimension (the time series) into the row dimension, and broadcast it into a 1D array and do some slicing? And I will include the pairwise looping (not element-wise) in the numexpr? Does that sound correct? My workflow is still in my notes haven't translated it into codes yet.

Comment: The usual way would be to flatten the y,x dims, then calc the pairwise diffs like `arr - arr[:, None]` but your array is too big for that, even looping over the z dim, you'll get a `MemoryError`.  I would look into using numba, keeping your explicit loops but wrapping  the loops into separate functions that you decorate with `@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)`.

Comment: I tried to decorate my functions with @jit. And, I have translated my loop into a function so I could decorate it with numba. But I'm getting an error which I can't understand. I think it has something to do with how I declare the object types. The link to the script is here with the error message at the bottom: https://www.dropbox.com/s/81uvfikzb03t3c5/test_pairwiseDistance_nb.py?dl=0